# Implementing Producer Consumer problem using lock on list

Tags: java, multithreading

This is an implementation of producer consumer pattern for a homework. What's wrong with the below implementation. It results in deadlock. I am not able to understand what went wrong.

I have a shared queue

I synchronize the producer and consumer on the same lock

```
private static volatile Queue<Integer> BUFFER = new LinkedList<>();
private static int COUNT = 0;
private static final int SIZE = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            while (BUFFER.size() == SIZE) {
                synchronized (BUFFER) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Producer waiting");
                        BUFFER.wait();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            synchronized (BUFFER) {
                System.out.println("Producer added : " + COUNT);
                BUFFER.offer(COUNT++);
                System.out.println("Producer notify");
                BUFFER.notify();
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500l);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

    new Thread(() -> {
        while (true) {
            while (BUFFER.isEmpty()) {
                synchronized (BUFFER) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Consumer waiting");
                        BUFFER.wait();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            synchronized (BUFFER) {
                System.out.println("Consumer consumed : "+ BUFFER.poll());
                BUFFER.notify();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500l);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).start();

}
```

}

This code results in deadlock after some time.

```
Producer added : 0
Producer notify
Consumer consumed : 0
Consumer waiting
Producer added : 1
Producer notify
Consumer consumed : 1
Producer added : 2
Producer notify
Consumer waiting
Producer waiting
```

Comment: Please, add the output into the question post as **text**. You may format it as a code. BTW, both buffer's size check and adding the element into the buffer should be under the **single critical section** (synchronize block).

Comment: Any access(r/w) to BUFFER must be synchronised. What you are doing it checking then synchronising.What you should do is Synchronise and then check because  between your check and synchronised block any other thread my change the state of shared BUFFER.

Comment: Any feedback on the below answers @Rajeev.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is susceptible to *lost notification*. Here's what could happen:

1. The consumer checks to see if the buffer is empty, and it *is* empty.
2. The producer puts an item into the buffer and calls `BUFFER.notify()`.
3. The consumer calls `BUFFER.wait()` (because the buffer was empty when it checked.)
4. The producer checks to see if the buffer is full, and it *is* full (`BUFFER.size() == 1`).
5. The producer calls `BUFFER.wait()`

Each thread now is waiting for the other to do something:  Deadlock!

The notification in step 2 was lost. `BUFFER.notify()` does not do anything at all if the other thread is not already waiting.

---

There's really only one right way to use `wait()` and `notify()`.  You can read about it here:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Comment: @Gray, What isn't right? It's a homework problem, and he asked "what went wrong?" I wanted to give him some insight into what probably went wrong, but I don't want to just do the assignment for him.  The Oracle "Guarded Blocks" tutorial spells out in detail what problem `wait()` and `notify()` were meant to solve, and how they should be used to solve it (including where and why to lock the lock.)

Comment: Sorry.  I thought that maybe you didn't get the wrinkle.  Your enumeration is right but it's going to be hard for someone to see so because the wait is inside of a while test of isEmpty().  That the locking is done in the wrong place isn't immediately apparent to a thread newbie.

Answer (score 0):

Using `notify` for producer consumer is not the right approach. 
Notifications are lost if nobody was actually waiting for that notification when the `notify()` is called.

Instead of using `wait()` and `notify()`, you should use a `semaphore`.

A shared `semaphore` can be released and acquired by any thread, and is the right tool to use in this type of inter-thread communication.

In that case a consumer will consume from the queue and  `release()` the `semaphore`. And the producer will `acquire()` the semaphore and push something into the queue.
If the queue is full, then the producer will block when it's trying to acquire the `semaphore` until a consumer empties the queue.
Unlike the *condition variable*, which you are basically using here, by using the `wait()` and `notify()`, the `semaphore` keeps state.

This is all discussed in great depth with examples for bound and unbound queues in the "*Java Multithreading, Concurrency & Performance Optimization*" course on Udemy.

It explains when to use condition variables and when and how to use a semaphore.

I hope it helps

Comment: This is not correct.  `notify()` is fine as long as the locking is right.

Comment: Gray, please see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify()
it notifies only a thread that is waiting for a notification. Of no thread is waiting when the notify is called, that notify is ignored and is missed

Comment: Uh, I understand that @Michael.  Check out my java multithreading score.  I'm just saying that using `notify()` can be done right.  `notify()` by itself is not the problem.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> What's wrong with the below implementation. It results in deadlock. I am not able to understand what went wrong.

```
while (BUFFER.isEmpty()) {
    synchronized (BUFFER) {
```

You code is close but the `synchronized` keyword must include the while loop here for it to work otherwise it will suffer from race conditions as enumerated by @SolomonSlow.  This is not a concurrent collection and although you mark it as `volatile` there is no guarantee that the `isEmpty()` method will return true, an element might be added to the list, and then the consumer enters the `synchronized` block.  You need to ensure that the test and the wait happen in the same lock.

Once you move the `synchronized` keyword, you can remove the `volatile` then because all accessing of the `BUFFER` is inside a `synchronized`.

```
synchronized (BUFFER) {
    while (BUFFER.size() == SIZE) {
...
synchronized (BUFFER) {
    while (BUFFER.isEmpty()) {
```

By moving the synchronized outside both of the while's, you code seems to work for me.

Couple of other comments:

- You can include the `System.out.println()` and `notify()` calls inside the original `synchronized`.  No need for 2 blocks there.
- Be careful of leaving the `e.printStackTrace();` and TODO.
- You shouldn't catch `Exception` but should instead make it as granular as possible.  `catch InterruptedException`.
- When you catch `InterruptedException` you should always re-interrupt the thread as a matter of policy.

  ```
  } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
      Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
      // now handle the interrupt by quitting the thread or something
  }
  ```